# Maximum number of triangles that can be formed with a given set of vertex points

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

We have a convex polygon with $M$ vertices, and $N$ points inside the polygon. Let $X$ be the set of these $M+N$ points. We know that there aren't $3$ collinear points in $X$.  We want to divide the polygon into triangles that have their vertices in $X$ and such that their sides intersect only in the vertices.  What is the maximum number of triangles we can obtain?

Comment: what happens when N=0 also what has been tried.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- How many triangles can you draw with $M$ external vertices and $0$ internal vertices?
- If you introduce an additional vertex inside an existing triangles, how many extra triangles can you draw (taking account of the one you break up)?

Comment: About the first question I think they are $M-2,$ but I’m not able to explain why... if it’s right, how can I explain this fact? I think it is connected to the fact that when I connect two vertices I can pass a number of points multiple of 3...

Comment: About the second question, what do you mean with "taking account of the one you break up"? I have to consider only the internal triangle, not the triangle I’m breaking up...

Comment: @MP625:  To see that when $N=0$ faces $F = M-2$:  Choose any vertex.  It is already connected to its neighbors.  So draw the only new edge that will create a triangle that cannot be split by another line... i.e., to a vertex two steps away.  Can you continue this process on your own?

Comment: @MP625  If you put a vertex inside an existing triangle, you can join it to the three vertices of that triangle making $3$ new triangles but losing the $1$ you started with

Comment: Ok, then I first form the $M-2$ triangles using the vertex of the polygon in the way said by @David G. Stork. Then I put a point in each triangle, until I can (I suppose $M>N.$ Hence i obtain $M-2+2N$ triangles. How can I be sure that this is the maximum?

Comment: There is no requirement for $M > N$, since if you insert an interior point and make new triangles, you can insert a new point and make even more.

Comment: Perhaps you could use $V=M+N$ and $3F = 2E-M$ and  $V+F=E+1$     for the general case of any full partition into triangles, not just from my algorithm. You could end up with $V=M+N$ vertices, $F=M-2+2N$ triangles, and $E=2M-3+3N$ edges (of which $M$ are on the original convex polygon and one triangle, while $M-3+3N$ are shared between two triangles).